# doxygen markdown prevent syntax highlighting in fenced code block

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, doxygen

I want a fenced code block to appear without any syntax highlighting. For the following code:

```
~~~
Behold this, for this is an orange.
~~~
```

I get `for` and `this` in color. Notice I have not specified the file extension. Do I need to specify a specific extension? I tried with `{.txt}`, but that didn't help.

Comment: use {.unparsed}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doxygen will apply syntax highlighting to a fenced code block based on either an explicit language (`{.cpp}`) or on the implicit language (the language of the code currently being parsed). If the language is not recognized, It appears to assume C/C++ syntax highlighting rules.

Unfortunately, this means that the code will be formatted according to one of the languages supported by Doxygen, and there isn't a way to trick it into displaying the fenced code block without syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to write a document which shows the console output when a specific command is run. Syntax highlighting it looks rather ugly and distracting.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options here.

- can use <pre> </pre> block. What ever is inside will be left displayed in a monospace font like a console.

You can use the <blockquote> </blockquote> which indents and places a vertical blue line to the left.

- alternatively you can use markdown and place a '>' and then a space before the text you want to show as output.

Answer (score 2):

with current versions of doxygen (i used 1.8.13) **using the `~~~`-syntax** without language specification **produces a code block without syntax highlighting**.
Common language specifications are

- `~~~{.cpp}` (C++)
- `~~~{.c}` (C)
- `~~~{.py}` (python)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mimic the styles that doxygen uses, which is done like this:

```cpp
/**
 * <div class="fragment">
 * <div class="line">Behold this, for this is an orange.</div>
 * <div class="line">General use:</div>
 * <div class="line">   ./SLAM_plus_plus -i <filename> --no-detailed-timing</div>
 * <div class="line"></div>
 * <div class="line">To run the pose-only datasets more quickly:</div>
 * <div class="line">   ./SLAM_plus_plus -i <filename> --pose-only --no-detailed-timing</div>
 * <div class="line"></div>
 * <div class="line">To run incrementally:</div>
 * <div class="line">   ./SLAM_plus_plus -nsp <optimize-each-N-verts> -fL -i <filename> --no-detailed-timing</div>
 * </div>
 */
```

While a bit elaborate (each line of text needs to be surrounded by its own `<div>`), it will get you what you want, with no highlighting. You might want to surroung this block with `\htmlonly` and `\endhtmlonly` to avoid whitespace condensation (otherwise sequences of multiple tabs / spaces are replaced by a single space *by Doxygen* - tweaking css will not help).

Alternately, you can use some more obscure language such as `{.f}` or `{.vhdl}` which Doxygen knows but which does not have keywords occurring in your text too much.